# VB.net table iteration

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have this code now. But it fails at three steps. Can you help me figure this out??

I have listed the three points where it fails.

Also please validate for me If I'm doing it right?

```
Retrieve the string from the tb_metatags textbox
Dim s As String
s = Me!tb_metaatags

parse the string into substrings by looking for the commasDim arrLines() As String
Dim arrLines() As String
arrLines = Split(s, ",")
For each substring, check if the substring is in the MetaSearchTags table
Dim itm As Variant
For Each itm In arrLines
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim numrows As Integer
    strsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MetaSearchTags WHERE SearchTag = " & itm & ""
    Dim objcmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, conn) "I get an error here
    numrows = objcmd.ExecuteScalar

    If numrows > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Record Exists", vbInformation, "Add") "I get an error here
    Else
    Dim myadapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO MetaSearchTags ( SearchTag) "VALUES ('" & itm & "')", conn) "I get an error here
    Dim mytable1 As New DataTable
    myadapter1.Fill (mytable1)
    End If

 if it is not already in the MetaSearchTags table, then add it to the table
get the primary key (ID) for the substring from the MetaSearchTags table
Add an row in the MetaSearchTagAssignments table for this search tag
using the projectID, and the substring ID from the MetaSearchTags table
Repeat this process for each substring entered in the field
```

Comment: It would be better if you commented your notes with apostrophes, so someone can just copy and paste your code. You need to also confirm the full error messages that you receive.

Comment: And removed the code formatting from the last paragraph altogether, as it's a text paragraph and has nothing to do with the code. Please [edit] it so that it's easier to read (and copy/paste). Also, while you're at it, post the details about what "I get an error" means, because "I get an error" has no meaning without specifics about the "error". You have an error message for each one; please share it, because we can't see them from here. :-)

Comment: What is the error you get on this line? `    Dim myadapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO MetaSearchTags ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put single quotes around strings in SQL statements:

```
strsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MetaSearchTags WHERE SearchTag = " & itm & ""
```

Should be:

```
strsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MetaSearchTags WHERE SearchTag = '" & itm & "'"
```

Comment: Those are not "brackets" (brackets are `[]`). They're single-quotes (`'`). Also, your final question should be a comment to the question itself, not part of your answer; it's asking for clarification of the question, and that information should be added to the question as an edit and not as a comment to an answer. (Not downvoting your answer; I'm just giving you a chance to correct it.)

Answer (score 0):

OleDbCommand.[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns

> The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null
>   reference if the result set is empty.

You need to handle this `null` reference (in VB.NET this equates to `Nothing`) when no records are returned.

One way to do this is:

```
Dim numrows as String = String.Empty

numrows = objcmd.ExecuteScalar()
If numrows Is Nothing Then
    'Do something with the error condition
Else
    'Do something with numrows which contains a valid result.
End If
```

(I would rename `numrows`)

You are also attempting to insert a record into the table even though no results are returned. This wouldn't be an error, but you have indicated (although it is a little difficult to interpret) that `SearchTag` is a primary key, in which case it will be an error to attempt to insert a duplicate.

And, as mentioned, you need to correct the quotes and apostrophes for your INSERT statement.